# How to retrieve value from database on selecting value from dropdown using Ajax?

Tags: java, ajax, database, jsp

I have a java servlet application where the database is populated by selecting an entry from a dropdown list and entering the values. On another page I have the same dropdown list and also have a find button to display the values that were previously entered by selecting an entry from the dropdown list. I want to get rid of this find button and dynamically display the previously entered values on this page. I heard this can be done using ajax. Please help me out.

Since the code is too much to share I have uploaded the snapshots of both the pages.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/10qmpxzwm8sik8a/1.PNG?dl=0
Here I am entering the values in estimate by selecting the project

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w8macftnm3rez3a/2.PNG?dl=0
Here I want to get the values just by selecting the project from the drop-down without clicking the Find button

Comment: can you post your code, or what did you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be specific with your question.
If I got you right...

You can use a variable in javasceipt  to hold the value that was enterd on the other page you got.

Then while using the dropdown on the other page you can retrieve the values that you store and use a simple ajax request with json data to your servelet.

Check here for examples: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/